# Back button saving position on scroll, but not forever?

Tags: web, squarespace

So I have a main page, with a few links to more detailed info. When they go to the more detailed info, i want the back button to return them to where they were in their scroll, rather than send them to the top of my home page every time.

I got something to work, but now, even if its been hours, or i closed the website, it sends me to a random position down the page.

Is there code out there that will reset this based on a timer, or if they close out of the page?

Thank you

Statestreetheadshots.com

i added code from a forum on ss